# Do any notable C extensions include integer types whose behavior is independent of machine word size

Tags: c, language-design, data-types

An interesting characteristic of C compared with some other languages is that many of its data types are based upon the word size of the target architecture, rather than being specified in absolute terms.  While this allows the *language* to be used to write code on machines that might have difficulty with certain types, it makes it very difficult to design code which will run consistently on different architectures.  Consider the code:

```
uint16_t ffff16 = 0xFFFF;
int64_t who_knows = ffff16 * ffff16;
```

On an architecture where `int` is 16 bits (still true of many small microcontrollers) this code would assign a value of 1 using well-defined behavior.  On machines where `int` is 64 bits, it would assign a value 4294836225, again using well-defined behavior.  On machines where `int` is 32 bits, it would likely assign a value of -131071 (I don't know if that would be Implementation-Defined or Undefined Behavior).  Even though the code uses nothing except what are nominally supposed to be "fixed-sized" types, the standard would require that two different kinds of compiler in use today would yield two different results, and many popular compilers today would yield a third.

<sub>This particular example is somewhat contrived, in that I would not expect in real-world code to assign the product of two 16-bit values directly to a 64-bit value, but it is was chosen as a brief example to show three ways integer promotions may interact with supposedly-fixed-sized unsigned types.  There are some real-world situations where it's necessary for math on unsigned types to be performed according to the rules of mathematical integer arithmetic, others where it's necessary that it be performed according to the rules of modular arithmetic, and some where it really doesn't matter.  A lot of real-world code for things like checksums relies upon `uint32_t` arithmetic wrapping mod 2³², and upon being able to perform arbitrary `uint16_t` arithmetic and get results which are, are at minimum, defined as being accurate mod 65536 (as opposed to triggering Undefined Behavior).</sub>

Even though this situation would clearly seem undesirable (and will become more so as 64- bit processing becomes the norm for many purposes), the C standards committee from what I've observed prefers to introduce language features which are already used in some notable production environments, rather than inventing them "from scratch".  Are there any notable extensions to the C language which would allow code to specify not just how a type will be stored but also how it should behave in scenarios involving possible promotions?  I can see at least three ways a compiler extension might resolve such issues:

1. By adding a directive that would instruct the compiler to force certain "fundamental" integer types to be certain sizes.
2. By adding a directive that would instruct the compiler to evaluate various promotion scenarios as though the machine's types had particular sizes, regardless of the actual sizes of the types on the target architecture.
3. By allowing means of declaring types with specific characteristics (e.g. declare that a type should behave as a mod-65536 wrapping algebraic ring, regardless of the underlying word size, and should not be implicitly convertible to other types; adding a `wrap32` to an `int` should yield a result of type `wrap32` regardless of whether `int` is larger than 16 bits, while adding a `wrap32` directly to a `wrap16` should be illegal (since neither could convert to the other).

My own preference would be the third alternative, since it would allow even machines with unusual word sizes to work with a lot of code that expects variables to "wrap" as they would with power-of-two sizes; the compiler may have to add bit-masking instructions to make the type behave suitably, but if code needs a type that wraps mod 65536, it's better to have the compiler generate such masking on machines that need it than to clutter the source code with it or simply have such code by unusable on machines where such masking would be needed.  I'm curious, though, whether there are any common extensions which would achieve portable behavior via any of the above means, or via some means I haven't thought of.

To clarify what I'm looking for, there are a few things; most notably:

1. While there are many ways by which code could be written so as to ensure desired semantics (e.g. defining macros to perform do math on particular-sized unsigned operands so as to yield a result which explicitly either wraps or does not) or at least prevent undesired semantics (e.g. conditionally-define a type `wrap32_t` to be `uint32_t` on compilers where a `uint32_t` would not get promoted, and figure that it's better for code which requires `wrap32_t` to fail compilation on machines where that type would get promoted than to have it run and yield bogus behavior), if there is any way of writing the code which would play most favorably with future language extensions, using that would be better than devising my own approach.
2. I have some pretty solid ideas for how the language could be extended so as to resolve many integer-size issues, allowing code to yield identical semantics on machines with different word sizes, but before I spend any significant time writing them up I'd like to know what efforts in that direction have already been undertaken.

I do not in any way wish to be seen as disparaging the C Standards Committee or the work they have produced; I expect, however, that within a few years it will become necessary to make code work correctly on machines where the "natural" promotion type would 32 bits, as well as those where it would be 64 bits.  I think with some modest extensions to the language (more modest than many of the other changes between C99 nnd C14) it would be possible to not only provide a clean way of efficiently using 64-bit architectures, but in the bargain also facilitate interaction with the "unusual-word-size" machines that the standard has historically bent over backward to support [e.g. making it possible for a machines with a 12-bit `char` to run code that expects an `uint32_t` to wrap mod 2³²].  Depending upon the direction future extensions take, I would also expect it should be possible to define macros which would allow code written today to be usable on today's compilers where the default integer types behave as "expected", but also usable on future compilers where integer types would be default behave differently, but where can provide the required behaviors.

Comment: `On machines where int is 64 bits, it would assign a value...`  No it won't.  That's *why* you use an `int64_t`:  it will always behave the same, regardless of the compiler or underlying machine.  How it is stored is an implementation detail which will unavoidably vary from system to system (having different `int` widths), but *that's what you want to have happen.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are you sure? As I understand *integer promotion*, if `int` is larger than `uint16_t`, the operands of the multiplication would be promoted to `int` and the multiplication would be carried out as `int` multiplication, and the resulting `int` value would be converted to `int64_t` for the initialization of `who_knows`.

Comment: @delnan: Then avoid the use of `int`.  Surely there's a way to do it without the integer promotion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How? In OP's code, there is no mention of `int` , yet it still sneaks in. (Again assuming my understanding of the C standard is correct.)

Comment: That would be a terrible oversight on the C committee's part.  The fundamental principle of cross-platform compatibility should be that operations from given code always produce the same result, regardless of the underlying platform.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure it sounds bad, but unless you can point out such a way, you're not contributing anything by saying "nah you must be doing something wrong". **The very question** is how to avoid the integer promotion, or get around its effects!

Comment: @supercat:  What is your ultimate goal?  Fastest possible speed?  Greatest platform independence?  Some combination of the two?  What prevents you from checking `sizeof(int)` and making the necessary adjustments to the math in your code?

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: You might want to use a [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library like [gmplib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: One of the historical goals of the C Standards Committee has been to make it possible for almost any machine to have a "C compiler", and have the rules be specific enough that independently-developed C compilers *for any particular target machine* would be mostly interchangeable.  This was complicated by the fact that people started writing C compilers for many machines before the standards were drafted, and *the Standards Committee did not want to forbid compilers from doing anything that existing code might rely upon*.  Some rather fundamental aspects of the standard...

Comment: ...are as they are not because anybody tried to formulate a set of rules that "made sense", but rather because the Committee was trying to nail down all the things that the independently-written compilers *that already existed* had in common. Unfortunately, this approach has led to standards which are simultaneously too vague to allow programmers to specify what needs to be done, but too specific to allow compilers to "just do it".

Comment: @delnan: Your understanding of the standard is probably the same as mine; I know that compilers are only supposed to define certain types if they behave according to the rules of two's-complement arithmetic, but I think that restriction only applies to e.g. `int32_t` rather than `uint16_t`; further, even if a compiler would require that `(int32_t)((uint32_t)ffff16 * ffff16);` would yield a two's-complement result, I don't think that implies that `ffff16*ffff16` wouldn't be Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @delnan: Further, while something like `(uint16_t)((uint32_t)ffff16*ffff16)` would be a portable way of performing the math according to mod-65536 arithmetic (in case one was e.g. doing certain kinds of checksum calculations) I'd consider that really ugly; it makes it look as though code wants to perform a 32-bit computation, when what it really wants is simply to get a result whose bottom 16 bits are correct.  On many smaller platforms, the latter could be achieved much more cheaply than the former, though compilers for such platforms may not optimize the code with the typecast.

Comment: @supercat  For clarity: The title "... any  C extensions include integer types ... independent of machine word size" is certainly true given the exact width type like `int16_t`, etc.  These types, if they can exist, are independent of machine word size.  Question is answered.  But it appears you want the more interesting question "... any  C extensions include integer _operators_ ... independent of machine word size".

Comment: @supercat I do not have a complete answer to your post.  With code like `int64_t who_knows = ffff16 * ffff16;`, using `int64_t who_knows = ffff16*1u * ffff16*1u;` solves _some_ of the issues in your test case, but not all.  Maybe `int64_t who_knows = (uint32_t) 1 * ffff16 * ffff16;` does.  I've been working a similar issue with [int2x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982992/how-to-determine-integer-types-that-are-twice-the-non-padding-bits-as-int-and)

Comment: @chux: Is the new title better? While `uint16_t` is supposed to behave as a 16-bit storage location, the behavior of type `uint16_t` in expressions will vary depending upon the underlying integer types.

Comment: @supercat  I think the new title well expresses your goal.  To my chagrin, I've found often the title and code are 99% of what many viewers see - all other text is so much noise.  Just look at any of my lowest rated questions - often because my title was not clear.

Comment: @supercat Any potentially narrower than `int/unsigned` types have the same problem as `uint16_t`, including `char`, `short`, etc.

Comment: @chux: Well, thanks for suggesting that I fix the title. Very useful comment. The biggest problems arise with types that are half the size of `int`, though other problems can exist with other types. The `char` type is also problematic. I really dislike the existence of distinct dialects of a language without a standard means of requesting one. IMHO, there should be a standard ways of saying "make `char` signed or refuse compilation if unable to do so" or "make `char` signed or refuse compilation if unable to do so".  Similar directives for the minimum-promotion size could...

Comment: ...also provide a good way to make code smoothly portable among machines with different register sizes.

Comment: `#if CHAR_MIN == 0 #error Need signed char #endif`

Comment: @chux: Some compilers provide command-line or #pragma options to control `char` signedness. An assertion would prevent code from compiling without the proper settings, but couldn't relieve the programmer from the requirement of manually applying the proper setting. A standardized directive could eliminate the need for such things. Further, it would be possible to make a nicely-implemented int-promotion directive be applicable within a narrow scope.  The fact that a particular method requires that the product of two `uint32_t` be `uint32_t` doesn't mean that all code should work that way.

Answer (score 4):

As the typical intention of code like this

```
uint16_t ffff16 = 0xFFFF;
int64_t who_knows = ffff16 * ffff16;
```

is to perform the multiplication in 64 bits (the size of the variable the result gets stored in), the usual way to get the (platform independent) correct result is to cast one of the operands to force a 64-bit multiplication:

```
uint16_t ffff16 = 0xFFFF;
int64_t i_know = (int64_t)ffff16 * ffff16;
```

I have never encountered any C extensions that make this process automatic.

Comment: My question was not how to force the correct evaluation of one particular arithmetic expression (depending upon which kind of result one wants, either cast an operand to `uint32_t` or else use a macro defined as either `#define UMUL1616to16(x,y)((uint16_t)((uint16_t)(x)*(uint16_t)(y)))` or `#define UMUL1616to16(x,y)((uint16_t)((uint32_t)(x)*(uint16_t)(y)))` depending upon the size of `int`) but rather whether there are any emerging standards for how to handle such things usefully rather than defining my own macros.

Comment: I should have also mentioned, that for things like hashing and checksum calculations, the purpose will often be to take a result and truncate it to the size of the operands.  The typical intention of an expression like `(ushort1*ushort2) & 65535u` would be to perform mod-65536 arithmetic for all operand values.  Reading the C89 rationale, I think it's pretty clear that while the authors recognized that such code might fail on some implementations if the result exceeded 2147483647, they expected such implementations to become increasingly rare.  Such code sometimes fails on modern gcc, however.